# How to edit translation file on the fly using some UI in angular 6?

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I am using ngx-translate in angular 6 application. I have two translation files en.json and nb.json in my assets folder. I have created UI to edit the values of the translation keys but now I am not finding any way to save the updated values in the translation file.

Can anyone suggest way how to accomplish this?

Comment: share your code please

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly edit your translation files from ui side.For that you have to

1.Put your translation files on server side

2.Load them using `ngx translate http module` [example here](https://christianlydemann.com/dynamic-translations-in-angular/)

3.Create api's using your server side lang to update these files

Comment: @Shikha no you can't do this using frontend only

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways in which you can achieve this.

1. Store the translation files to the database and make an HTTP call to retrieve the latest translations. Not an efficient way, increases the load on server and Database.
2. Use Firebase RTDB to store the translations, you can use [AngularFire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2) to fetch and store translations data. Cache the translations with a timestamp and update the cache only when new translations are available. This will put less load on the server and you can update your translations with ease. In case you want a similar feature in the mobile app, send a push notification with a data payload, and update the latest translations.